# CefSharp.Wpf 55 causes some WPF graphical artifacts on some hardware

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, cefsharp

We are using the NuGet CefSharp.Wpf 55.0.0 to display websites inside our WPF application. We are having issues on one x64 laptop running Windows 10.

Other WPF-components (like Telerik) outside of CefSharp are glitching out when CefSharp is included. Images are drawn out and blurred and other strange artifacts appear. We have tried disabling the gpu acceleration for CefSharp without success.

Setting `RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = System.Windows.Interop.RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;` in the application process removes the artifacts. Also, chrome://gpu/ shows no information on this machine - only the headers inside the page are shown when viewing the page, not the usual listing of hardware capabilities and such.

CefSharp itself renders perfectly normal. There are no issues on 3 out of the 4 tested machines.

**Update**

GitHub issue: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1961

Comment: Please cross link your posts https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1961

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We moved the AnyCpu-fixes from the constructor to the Application.Current.Startup-event and suddenly everything just seems to work.

Check out the GitHub issue for more details: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1961